# Laravel 5.3 query builder error with MSSQL

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

new install laravel error when using DB:select 
the backtrace is

```
FatalErrorException in SqlServerConnection.php line 13:

Declaration of Illuminate\Database\SqlServerConnection::transaction(Closure $callback) must be compatible with 

Illuminate\Database\ConnectionInterface::transaction(Closure $callback, $attempts = 1)
```

My setup is PHP 7.0 , laravel 5.3, ubuntu server 16.04, apache2.

The code just as simple in routes/web.php as :

```
Route::get('/', function () { DB::select('select @@version'); });
```

Yup they work on 5.2. It also run artisan migrate on 5.2 with success. Now i wanna update laravel to 5.3. Even fresh install give me the same error

Comment: Please show the SQL statement you are trying to run

Comment: just a simple one : select @@version

Comment: and maybe some code

Comment: Route::get('/', function () {
    DB::select('select @@version');
});

Comment: Your MS SQL settings pan out? Do they work with Laravel 5.2?

Comment: Yup they work on 5.2. It also run artisan migrate on 5.2 with success. Now i wanna update laravel to 5.3. But fresh install give me the same error.

Comment: Just tried it myself, seems like a Laravel 5.3 bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in 5.3 and will be fixed in 5.3.1
See also:
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/14992#issuecomment-242006433